# Why is dx or dy width during rotation of a function around an axis?

Tags: calculus

For example

[image]

Why is dx the width? Isn't dx infinitely small?

Thank you

Comment: Without seeing the figure, it's hard to tell...

Answer (score 1):

In problems like this, $dx$ is the infinitesimal width. Recall the definition of an integral:

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x)\Delta x$$

Without the limit, this is the sum of the area a bunch of rectangles, with the limit we get the sum of infinitely many rectangles of infinitesimal width, and height equal to $f(x)$. The argument is similar in this case, you are taking some function, and rotating it about some axis. You can calculate the volume by stacking a bunch of cylinders of radius $f(x)$ and infinitesimal width $dx$.